# Strange result with Laplace transform

Tags: bugs, integral-transforms, version-12.2

The following code:

```
f[x_] := HeavisideTheta[1 - x]/x
InverseLaplaceTransform[ f[t], t, x]/x
```

Returns `1/x`. But this should not be the case because the function `1/x` is invariant under this transform and its inverse `LaplaceTransform[ t f[t], t, x]`. Applying the later transform to the result should return the original function.

Is this a bug?

**UPDATE**

With `GenerateConditions`, the operator `InverseLaplaceTransform[(1-E^-x)/x, x, t, GenerateConditions -> True]`  gives `0` which is wrong (without options the result is correct).

**UPDATE2**

Tested on Wolfram Engine 12.1, it seems to give a correct result, so this is likely a 12.1->12.2 regression.

Comment: lets take one step back for a second. Mathematica gives answer to `InverseLaplaceTransform[HeavisideTheta[1 - t]/t, t, x]`  as `1`. Are you saying this is a wrong answer? What should the correct answer be?

Comment: @Nasser yes, this is wrong. I do not know what should be the correct answer, but ```LaplaceTransform[ 1, t, x]``` returns ```1/x```, not ```HeavisideTheta[1-x]/x```.

Comment: @xzczd if one uses function ```E^-x/x```, it automatically produces correct result using ```HeavisideTheta```

Comment: @xzczd with ```GenerateConditions```, the operator ```InverseLaplaceTransform[ f[t], t, x]/x``` applied to ```(1 - E^-x)/x``` gives  ```0``` which is wrong (without options the result is correct). Is there a way to obtain the correct result always?

Comment: Seems that `InverseLaplaceTransform[(-E^-x)/x, x, t, GenerateConditions -> True]` gives incorrect output in _v12.2_. Please report it to WRI.

Comment: @xzczd Adding tag "bug" then.

Comment: @xzczd by the way, I have read about the GenerateConditions option, but still I think it is unrelated here. The result should not be 1/x without that option as well.

Comment: After a closer look I think you're right. `f[x_] = HeavisideTheta[1 - x]/x;
InverseLaplaceTransform[f[s], s, x]` returns unevaluated in _v9.0.1_ BTW.